# Delete and Retrieve AWS Cognito identity inside Cognito Federated Identity Pool

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, amazon-cognito, federated-identity

I configured the identity pool with cognito user pool and Facebook as providers. Enable access to unauthenticated identities. Used javascript sdk to connect from browser. Got an identity (unauthenticated of course) back. Now, just for kicks, I deleted the identity from identity browser. After that I am getting 400 error with "ResourceNotFoundException".

I am a newbie playing with AWS Cognito Identity Pool. I have a silly question which I could not find answer anywhere. When/Why do we delete identity from Identity Pool ( either from identity browser via console, or via API ) ?

Now, Once I delete an identity, how do I connect back using the same device/browser ?

TIA

Comment: Partha, could you share your code? I'm trying to use Identity Pools (all setup) in my User Pool (also setup) now and am having trouble understanding what AWS SDKs to use for the Identity Pool piece. I can login via User Pools only.

Comment: It is been a while. I will lookup to see if I find them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's various reasons you might want to delete identities. For example, if you're just working on integrating the service into your application and want clean, manageable test data.

Each of the SDKs has a utility method to clear the local storage (i.e. in Android it's credentialsProvider.clear()). The resource not found you're getting is because the SDK has cached the identity id it will be using, so you'll want to call that from whichever SDK you're using after deleting and you'll be good to go.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was using Javascript SDK, could clear the cache by AWS.config.credentials.clearCachedId(); I got what I needed. Thanks again.