# How to create a new identity on same device in AWS Cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I'm new to using AWS Cognito and have run into a problem- I have managed to get an unauthenticated id on an app to create a datasheet in cognito. However, I deleted this ID through the AWS Cognito dashboard just to see what would happen, and to hopefully be able to authenticate with facebook. Is there a way to do this successfully? I am getting an error that the "identity XXX not found."

```
let token = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString

    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(regionType:.USXXX,
                                                            identityPoolId:"XXXX-XXX-XXXXXX")

    print(credentialsProvider.getIdentityId())


    credentialsProvider.logins = [AWSCognitoLoginProviderKey.Facebook.rawValue: token]

    let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region:.USXXX, credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

Also, any direction on the difference between federated and non-federated identities would be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exactly had this problem. SDK caches it. You just need to clear the cache. More infromation here. [Delete and Retrieve AWS Cognito identity inside Cognito Federated Identity Pool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39093898/delete-and-retrieve-aws-cognito-identity-inside-cognito-federated-identity-pool)

Comment: Cognito developer here - this is a fair solution to the problem. The issue is the SDK caches the identity id and doesn't know it was deleted, so if you're deleting from the console while testing a hook like this makes sense.

Comment: @JeffBailey How would one go about getting creating a new cognito ID with the facebook token? I'm logging in with facebook, then if the user is already logged in, I'm calling the AWS Cognito code seen above. However, in the aws cognito dashboard in federated identities, it still shows 0 users that have authenticated with Facebook.

Comment: Add the new login token to the logins map and get a new set of credentials.